# How can I solve this error at deploy my application?

Tags: node.js

I deployed my application with Vercel. Site navigation seems to work, but if I refresh the page, the following error appears. Does anyone know how[[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vuJH2.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sOl5y.png) can I fix it? I'm using Typescript and React

Does anyone know how can I fix it? Thank you!

Comment: Are you using client routing instead of server routing?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: @RobinThomas I think I'm using server-side routing. How can I verify if I'm using server-side routing?

Comment: I would assume its client route, since on refresh (it tries to pull from server), and gets 404 (meaning route doesnt exist in server). Can you share your code?